# Problem with importing discord.py modules

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

StackOverflow.
I've been having a problem with a discord bot, here's the script:

```
    def send():
        url = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/762125650546131005/lgYkjh-ILrag2sb3nzqUZfF1sg2mN2a0QeABaUq9dwl7qBTNL4EqWV00K62xWZ8_sNQ5"
        data = {}
        data["content"] = ""
        data["username"] = "Suggestions"

        data["embeds"] = []
        embed = {}

        embed["description"] = "**Author** » <@" + str(message.author.id) + ">\n **Suggestion** » " + str(args)
        embed["title"] = "**New Suggestion!**"
        data["embeds"].append(embed)

        result = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

    send()

    await message.author.send("Thank you for your suggestion! We will look into it as soon as possible and will message you if it will be used.")
```

When I do ";suggestion fix bugs" it just sends to the webhook "fix" which is only the first word and I am struggling to fix this. Please may someone help?

Comment: afaik you should censor your webhook link, as anyone can send messages to it. As for an answer, I can't explain anything yet but you might want to take a look at the discord.py docs on the [Webhook object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#webhook-support)

Comment: Hey, I don't mind about the webhook as I need to change it anyway but thanks for the response :)

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the command's arguments; can you show the full code to the function, or at least the arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use requests with discord.py, it is sync and will block your bot, use a [discord.Webhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20webhook#discord.Webhook) with [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html) to send a [discord.Embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed)

Example:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async with ClientSession() as session:
    wh = discord.Webhook.from_url("<webhook url>", adapter=discord.AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))

    e = discord.Embed()
    e.title = "Hello I am an Embed"
    ...

    await wh.send(embed=e)
```